# Traverse triangles in Triangulation of 2-sphere without repetition (Hamiltonian Path)

Tags: graph-theory, combinatorial-geometry, hamiltonian-path

Let $T_0, \dots, T_n$ be a collection of spherical triangles that form a triangulation of the $2$-sphere.

Can we enumerate the triangles in such a manner that $T_{i-1}$ and $T_{i}$ have exactly one common edge for all $1 \leq i \leq n$? Can we enumerate them such that $T_n$ and $T_0$ have one common edge?

This question can be seen through the lense of graph theory: let $V$ be a graph whose vertices are the triangles, and let $E$ be the set of edges (quite literally). The question is whether the graph G=(V,E) has a Hamiltonian path or a Hamiltonian tour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope!

Finding a Hamiltonian cycle is almost equivalent to [Tait's Hamiltonian Graph Conjecture](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TaitsHamiltonianGraphConjecture.html)
that every cubic polyhedral (i.e. 3-connected planar) graph is Hamiltonian. That is because every cubic polyhedral graph gives you a convex polyhedron with all 3-valent vertices, whose dual is a polyhedron with all triangular faces, which induces a triangulation of the 2-sphere.

The counterexamples to Tait's conjecture thus give you triangulations of the 2-sphere with no Hamiltonian cycle among the triangles.

For Hamiltonian *paths*, the question is whether every 3-connected planar cubic graph is [traceable](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TraceableGraph.html). I didn't find anyone discussing merely untraceable graphs, but there are several papers looking more specifically for [hypotraceable graphs](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypotraceableGraph.html) (which have no Hamiltonian path, but removing any vertex leaves a graph with a Hamiltonian path).

Carsten Thomassen's 1981 paper "Planar Cubic Hypohamiltonian and 
Hypotraceable Graphs" ([DOI 10.1016/0095-8956(81)90089-7](https://doi.org/10.1016/0095-8956(81)90089-7)) has

> THEOREM 3.1. There exist infinitely many planar cubic hypohamiltonian 
>   graphs and infinitely many planar cubic hypotraceable graphs.

Investigating the relevant construction from his 1976 paper "Planar and infinite hypohamiltonian and hypotraceable graphs" ([DOI 10.1016/0012-365X(76)90071-6](https://doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(76)90071-6)),
we find that it yields 3-connected graphs, so these are polyhedral and give rise to untraceable 2-sphere triangulations.

The smallest of these hypotraceable graphs has 460 vertices.
["On cubic planar hypohamiltonian
and hypotraceable graphs" (M. Araya, G. Wiener, 2011)](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v18i1p85)
finds smaller examples, in

> Corollary 3.2. There exists a cubic planar hypotraceable graph on 340
>   vertices and on $n$ vertices for every even number  $n ≥ 356$.